# How to place excel VBA code on save event

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run below VBA code when I save the excel document. I can able to run this code at once but (Not on save) it's not working anymore. Could you please help me how can I run this code on save?

It's in Module :

```
'Option Explicit
'
'Sub CopyToOtherCell()
'
'Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer
'
'LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'
'For i = 2 To LastRow
'    If Cells(i, 12).Value = Date Then
'        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 12)).Select
'        Selection.Copy
'        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Murat\Desktop\Proposal_Admin.xlsx"
'        Worksheets("sheet1").Select
'        erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'        ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
'        ActiveSheet.Paste
'        ActiveWorkbook.Save
'        ActiveWorkbook.Close
'        Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    End If
'Next i
'
'End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried it with both ways mentioned below but doesn't worked ;  
1 - IN MODULE :
Option Explicit 
Sub CopyToOtherCell() 
Code... 
End Sub    
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
CopyToOtherCell
End Sub
2 – IN “This Workbook” (With Workbook & Beforesave selected above) 
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim LastRow.... Code.....
End Sub

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but the **BeforeSave** Event fires just before saving the file.

So you would need to put the following in ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As   Boolean)

CopyToOtherCell

End sub
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. Yes I'm trying to use it as below ;

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment I did it.