# Is it possible to assign a value to a cell when saving an excel file?

Tags: excel

The point would be to automatically keep a "last" value (without, the human-error-prone: "just remember to do it" method), so that when changes are made the next time the spreadsheet is updated, they can be easily compared.

Update:

I'd still prefer to do this without macros, if possible.

But, since that's apparently not possible; what would the macro look like to do this?

Comment: Well, I guess you're out of luck then. A macro would be the only way to do this, because there is no formula available that is automatically triggered on a save operation.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean to keep a last value?  Do you have any example that you want to implement?

Comment: @ian0411 the value as of the last save.

Comment: Do you mean something like a batch processing number or datetime that someone used from last save?

Comment: @ian0411 An example would be you do whatever in a sheet to calculate the  cost of something.    And next time you use the file you make a small change to one value in the calculation.  This causes the result to change.  So, the goal is to see the  the both results values, the last one and the current one. Without multiple files or duplicating sheets.  Just save the last result to a "last" cell and otherwise keep putting the current result in a "normal result cell.

Comment: Interesting...  Currently I don't think there is a way without VBA.  Maybe you can use an `Auto_open` VBA when the user opens up the spreadsheet.  But let me ponder this for a few days if you insists to have it without VBA.

Comment: maybe compare the Last Save Time Document Property https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/last_modified.php

Answer (score 0):

[How to place excel VBA code on save event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628769/how-to-place-excel-vba-code-on-save-event)

You can use an event trigger. I think you have to have a macro. You're basically asking this to be automatic - which means having to code something to do it for you. Using a spreadsheet formula would mean it will display current values... it wouldn't stick to the last value.