# Saving data in one file and having the output go to another file every time it is saved

Tags: vba, excel, loops

In one tab I have information, where I have made it output the information on a second tab (It's more in depth than this but I tried making this as simple as possible)
[image]
refer to this as (1)

I want to make another file where every time that (1) is saved, the information from Tab 2 of (1) stacks up in (2) below:

[image]
refer to this as (2)

I'm guessing this is Macro based, but I am not sure how to do so.

To clarify, the first time someone saves data to Tab 1 in (1) it's output is sent to Tab 2 in (1). Then I want that data to be saved to the new file, (2), as X Y Z. The next time someone saves the data in (1), I want it to pop up in the new file (2) as A B C. So every time the file is saved, new data forms on the new file, (2).

---

Provided code from OP (taken from comments):

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click() 
    Dim Name As String 
    Dim Date As String 
    Dim State As String 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select FileName = Range("B1") 
    EffectiveDate = Range("B2") 
    State = Range("B3") 
    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("H: \NameDateState.xlsx") 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select 
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select 
    RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count 
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A1") .Offset(RowCount, 0) = Name 
        .Offset(RowCount, 1) = Date 
        .Offset(RowCount, 2) = State 
    End With 
    myData.Save 
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place excel VBA code on save event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628769/how-to-place-excel-vba-code-on-save-event)

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: Tag me later in case this is updated so i can remove my downvote for lack of info.  Stack Overflow is a collaborative site for fixinig *specific* coding issues, not a code-for-you service.  If you need help getting started, try using the Macro Recorder in the Developer tab of Excel.

Comment: "In one tab I have information, where I have made it output the information on a second tab" - it is unreadable.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

     Dim Name As String
     Dim Date As String
     Dim State As String

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
FileName = Range("B1")
EffectiveDate = Range("B2")
State = Range("B3")

Set myData = Workbooks.Open("H: \NameDateState.xlsx")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = Name
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = Date
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = State
End With
myData.Save
End Sub

Comment: ^^ I apologize for not indenting, first time using this site, not sure how to properly do so. Also I just started VBA this week. I am getting a defect at dim date as string, ive tried dim date as date and am also getting a defect. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cyril . Let's see what you're made of

Comment: @dhunited12 Please edit your question to include your code... putting it in comments does little for readability.

Comment: @dhunited12 Regarding Dim Date as String, you need to use something that isn't a pre-defined term in VBA.  Dim DateStr as String would work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what we can do...  You want data moved from Sheets(1) to tab Sheets(2), then you want Sheets(2) moved to a new file and that file saved (possibly closed).

If that's the case, you will need to do a couple things, some of which might help your coding in the long run:

- 1) Avoid .Select/.Activate where possible
- 2) Use Option Explicit at the top of your module, before you begin listing out subroutines (will force you to declare all variables)

---

Let's break down your problem a little further... you have one designated location on Sheets(1) to input data, which will be *entered* (from a click button) to Sheets(2).  We'll assume your headers are in column 1 ("A") and inputs are to column 2 ("B"):

```
dim lrd as long
With Sheets(2)
    lrd = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    .Cells(lrd+1,1).Value = Sheets(1).cells(1,2).Value  'Date
    .Cells(lrd+1,2).Value = Sheets(1).cells(2,2).Value  'State
    .Cells(lrd+1,3).Value = Sheets(1).cells(3,2).Value  '# People
    'You will probably want to clear data from the input cells after that
    Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(1,2),Sheets(1).Cells(3,2)).ClearContents
End With
```

Ok, the data now exists in Sheets(2).  You now want Sheets(2) to .Copy (takes a sheet to a new workbook):

```
Sheets(2).Copy
```

Then SaveAs the new workbook, then save/close:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\NameOfFile.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

That should leave you with a input workbook open.  I would recommend doing some naming of the file based on somethign more dynamic, though I have provided a fixed situation.  Note that your source file would be xlsm, and saving as xlsx would remove macros from the new workbook in case anything gets carried over.

---

Altogether, it looks like:

```
dim lrd as long
With Sheets(2)
    lrd = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    .Cells(lrd+1,1).Value = Sheets(1).cells(1,2).Value  'Date
    .Cells(lrd+1,2).Value = Sheets(1).cells(2,2).Value  'State
    .Cells(lrd+1,3).Value = Sheets(1).cells(3,2).Value  '# People
    'You will probably want to clear data from the input cells after that
    Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(1,2),Sheets(1).Cells(3,2)).ClearContents
End With
Sheets(2).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\NameOfFile.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```