# Excel: Force recalculate on save

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a simple macro that returns the date of the last save of the current document:

```
Function LastSavedTimeStamp() As Date
  LastSavedTimeStamp = INT(ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time"))
End Function
```

This works fine when I manually force the cell to re-calcutate, but the cell doesn't re-calculate when I save the sheet - which is what I want. Is there a way to ensure that the macro above is run everytime the document is saved, such that the date of last save is automatically updated.

PS. This will only work when macros are enabled. That is fine.

---

I.e. this is what I want

[image]

---

Try 2: Inspired by Skin

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628769/how-to-place-excel-vba-code-on-save-event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place excel VBA code on save event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628769/how-to-place-excel-vba-code-on-save-event)

Comment: Make the function [volitile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile)

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have, as I see it, is that you want to save the document with the last saved value.  This a chicken and egg issue though.  You won't get the last saved value until it's saved ...!

To trick it, firstly, I suggest adding `Application.Volatile` to your current function ...

```
Function LastSavedTimeStamp() As Date
    Application.Volatile
    
    LastSavedTimeStamp = Int(ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time"))
End Function
```

.. that way, it will force the recalculation when the document is saved and anytime a calculation runs.

Then, in your `ThisWorkbook` object, add the below code ...

```
Public DO_NOT_CALCULATE As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet

    If Not DO_NOT_CALCULATE Then
        For Each objWorksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            objWorksheet.Calculate
        Next
        
        DO_NOT_CALCULATE = True
        
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    Else
        DO_NOT_CALCULATE = False
    End If
End Sub
```

That will save the workbook again after the initial save forcing the recalculation to make sure your cell has the correct value.

It's a bit ugly but it should work for you.

Comment: I tried doing as you suggest, but it isn't working. I have added pictures to the post. Perhaps Grove is right that there is something that isn't running as it should? I.e. that the 'event handler' isn't firing

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint?

Comment: No, or at least not intentionally. I have never used breakpoints in Excel

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/set-and-clear-a-breakpoint … https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html … try that and see if they fire.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to put a call to this function in the BeforeSave event sub procedure of the work book module.

[image]

Here's the code to paste in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    LastSavedTimeStamp
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I added the code as you posted it, but nothing changes in the save behaviour - I don't get an automatic update of the date. I have updated the question

Comment: When I try and do as you suggest I don't see the "Option Explicit"

Comment: The "option explicit" directive is not required.  It just tells the compiler to require all variables to be declared before they can be used.

Comment: Try changing "LastSavedTimeStamp" to 'msgbox "about to save" ' as ssee if that displays a message box when you save.  This will let you know if your code the event handler is firing

Comment: I think you might be on to something: msgbox "about to save" didn't work (with our without ')